# How to achieve seamless SSO without having the user to login in IdP (SAML2.0) in java

Tags: java, saml-2.0

is it possible to send SAML 2.0 request to idp and here user is not going to login in IDP,and idp will send the response to sp.please suggest me for POC in java.
please share any link or any thing .Google in confusing me instead of solution.

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat recently released a new web single sign-on (SSO) server, based on the upstream Keycloak project. Now you have an out-of-the-box SAML 2.0 or OpenID Connect-based identity provider, fully supported, which mediates with your enterprise user directory or third-party identity provider for identity information and your applications via standards-based tokens.

[Identity Brokering  in keycloak](http://blog.keycloak.org/2015/03/customizing-keycloak.html)

[keycloak website](http://www.keycloak.org/)

Comment: thanks @sagar-routhu ...but i need more information...actually my client having already one support system and they are using ,now we are providing our own support system to them.so basically they don't want separate login for both support system .so here my task to send a authentication request to them in based on SAML 2.0 protocal to them for authentication.but here my product is not develop in SAML 2.0.So basically i need to create one one sample app that will send a saml req to idp without login there and get a response.please guide what to do.